# PHP can't connect to MySQL: mysqli.so file not loading?

Tags: php, mysqli, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database using php on Amazon ec2, but it does not even return an error message. I think it's because mysqli.so is not loading.

My php:

```
<?php
require_once "login.php";
$db_server = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$db_server):
    echo ("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
?>
```

login.php contains the login details for my MySQL used.

I have run

```
php -m | grep mysqli
```

Which returns

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
mysqli
```

`/use/lib64/php/modules/` doesn't contain `mysqli.so`.

I have not been able to find `mysqli.so` in another location and I have added the line `extension=mysqli.so` to the top of my `php.ini` file and I don't know what I can try next.

My login.php file as requested (the Xs are my username and password which I have used to log in over ssh):

```
<?php
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_database = 'publications';
$db_username = 'XXX';
$db_password = 'XXX';
?>
```

Comment: I notice you miss an $ sign in front of db_server on line 3

Comment: and you're using mysql_connect, I don't see mysqli anywhere in you're code

Comment: Good spot @davejal , but had the $ sign in my actual code. Updated my question to use new mysqli, still nothing

Comment: I think the problem is in your login.php, could you share that with us?

Comment: Login.php is there now @davejal

Comment: I haven't worked with amazon ec2, but usually the host_name shouldn't be localhost. Second you created the database publiciations, but when calling to open you're missing the db value (on line 3 also). Normally this woudln't be a problem, but maybe ec2 has a restriction

Answer (score 0):

Could you try these to troubleshoot any further

1. turn on error logging

   ```
   <?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
       ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
       ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
   $mysql = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password); //maybe it is required to add your database_name here
   if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
   die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
   }
   ?>
   ```

   ---
2. try to echo php info

either this:

```
<?php echo 'Configuration file (php.ini) path: ', get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');
```

or

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

// Show just the module information.
// phpinfo(8) yields identical results.
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);

?>
```